# Linux naming/names

Tags: kernel, disk

i have been trying to understand a concept which i have encountered in the past days.

i have heard that in kernel version 2.9 of the linux kernel there was a change in how IDE/PATA and SATA/SCSI devices were being supported, im not really sure what happend here so can someone please clearly explain to me what happend here. as a result of this i have heard that the IDE hard drive naming was changed from hd* to sd*, but why is this and what caused this to happend, what changes were made?

if someone could explain this too me it would be of great help,
from my understanding is that the Linux kernel introduced a brand new library called LibATA, im not quite sure what this does.

Comment: Please, read carefully what I've already sent you everything is there : https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_19#Libata_PATA_.28Parallel_ATA.29_merge

Comment: If you need to clarify the question marked as a duplicate, then do so by editing that question.